# Page throws JavaScript runtime error: 'Function name' is undefined. IE10 only

Tags: javascript, asp.net

While working on IE10, I have found that the JavaScript functions which are registered or called from the code behind are throwing exception:

> "JavaScript runtime error: 'function name' is undefined".

For ex:
Code behind in the (!IsPostBack) block:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("showGCAlert", "<script language=\"javascript\">ShowGCAlert();</script>");
```

PageView:

```
function ShowGCAlert()
    {

        alert('GCAlert');
        if(document.getElementById('hdnGCAlert').value != "1")
        {
            document.getElementById('divGCAlert').style.display = "Block";
            document.getElementById('chkReminder').focus();
            document.getElementById('btnLogin').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = true;             

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('divGCAlert').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('btnLogin').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = false;                
            if (document.getElementById("txtUsername").value != "")
                document.getElementById("txtPassword").focus();
            else
                document.getElementById("txtUsername").focus();
        }

    }
```

When the page loads its throws the exception even though the `ShowGCAlert()` exists on the dynamic page.

After continuing the exception design page shows:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/ABC/DEF/Scripts/Common.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    document.body.style.overflowY="hidden";
    document.body.style.overflowX="hidden";
    var jsAppName ='ABC';
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    function window.onresize() 
    { 
        document.cookie = "resX=" 
                        + document.body.clientWidth 
                        + ";resY=" 
                        + document.body.clientHeight 
                        + ";path=/"; 
    } 
    window.onresize();
</script>
<script type="javascript">
      ShowGCAlert();
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById('txtPassword').focus();
</script>
```

In ie9 or IE10 compatibility view its working fine. Please show me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using the non-deprecated version inside of ClientScriptManager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @LastCoder Yes, just now i have used this.. but still showing the exception.

Comment: 6th line from the end up: `<script type=text/javascript>` Is this typo just here in your question? It should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the script at the end of the page using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and call it.

```
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("showGCAlert", 
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\">ShowGCAlert();</script>");
```

Comment: Still giving the exception.

Comment: @Maybe2013, could you please check the view source and tell us where the function call and function is placed?

Comment: Updated the ques.. please see if this is you want?

Comment: And if alert('hi') is called from the RegisterStartupScript then its not giving the exception.

Comment: @Maybe2013, changed the language to `type=text/javascript` in my answer. Try it

Comment: thanx for the answer. after updating code, now the exception does'nt show but inside the ShowGCAlert()...alert('hi') is written and it  dint show the HI message on page load.

Comment: @Maybe2013, make sure you calling the function `ShowGCAlert();` with `;` also show us the code inside `ShowGCAlert`

Comment: @Maybe2013, Thats cool. Check this[post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) if you want to force a browser to choose a mode