# Throws JavaScript runtime error: 'Function name' is undefined. IE10 only, works in compatibility view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

All of the code behind registered javascripts are throwing exception in page loads.

Registering JS function like this:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("showGCAlert", "<script language=\"javascript\">ShowGCAlert();</script>");
```

This only give exception IE10 even IE 10 compatibility view works fine.
Also tried

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("showGCAlert", 
     "<script type=\"text/javascript\">ShowGCAlert();</script>");
```

Please mention whats wrong with the IE 10.

PS: it was an old .net 1.1 project, we converted into .net 4.0 and everything worked fine fine in ie9 and even ie10 compatibility view but not in IE10.

Comment: Try **var aa=ShowGCAlert();**

Comment: @dholakiyaankit did not understand yourr reply

Comment: maybe its may be situation in my reply

Comment: Probably `</script>` in a string is causing troubles here, try this: `<\/script>`

Comment: Is this duplicate from one day old Q [Page throws JavaScript runtime error: 'Function name' is undefined. IE10 only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100136/page-throws-javascript-runtime-error-function-name-is-undefined-ie10-only#comment29951666_20100136)?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic Yes both are related but dint find answer for any of them...Sorry for duplicating it.